# Pandas copy rows using loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   SNFrom  SNTo  Name  Age
0       1     4  John    8
1       5     7  Jack    6
```

Using `pandas`, I want to produce a result like this:

```
   Name  Age  SN
0  John    8   1
1  John    8   2
2  John    8   3
3  John    8   4
4  Jack    6   5
5  Jack    6   6
6  Jack    6   7
```

The general rule is that I want to add new rows, based on the ranges specified in `SNFrom`, and `SNTo`, so for example, `John` should have rows 1-4, and `Jack` should have rows 5-7.

Comment: Please do not put image those are really hard to reproduce and time consuming either, rather update your post and put  your data there , how it looks like now and what you expect as a desired output, this way it will be easy to read and easy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively naïve way using `apply`:

## Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SNFrom':[1,5],'SNTo':[4,7],'Name':['John','Jack'],'Age':[8,6]})
>>> df
   Age  Name  SNFrom  SNTo
0    8  John       1     4
1    6  Jack       5     7
```

## Solution:

```
new_df = (df.set_index(['Name','Age'])[['SNFrom','SNTo']]
          .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(range(x.SNFrom, x.SNTo+1))),1)
          .stack()
          .reset_index(level=[0,1])
          .rename(columns={0:'SN'}))

>>> new_df
   Name  Age   SN
0  John    8  1.0
1  John    8  2.0
2  John    8  3.0
3  John    8  4.0
0  Jack    6  5.0
1  Jack    6  6.0
2  Jack    6  7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized solution using `np.repeat`:

```
s = df.SNTo - df.SNFrom
i = np.repeat(df.index, s+1)
t = df.loc[i, ['Name', 'Age', 'SNFrom']]

t.assign(SN=t.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + t.SNFrom).drop('SNFrom', 1)
```

```
   Name  Age  SN
0  John    8   1
0  John    8   2
0  John    8   3
0  John    8   4
1  Jack    6   5
1  Jack    6   6
1  Jack    6   7
```